sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: PostgreSQL ENUM type requires a name
I have tried multiple solutions but nothing seems to be working. I have this code
from models.business import db
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Enum
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

days_of_week = ('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday')
                
day_of_week_enum = ENUM(*days_of_week,name='days_of_week_enum',create_type=False)


class WorkingHours(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'working_hours'


    business_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('business.business_id'),primary_key = True)
    business = db.relationship("Business", back_populates="working_hours")
    client_id = db.Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), db.ForeignKey('client.client_id'))
    day_of_week =db.Column(day_of_week_enum)
    start_time = db.Column(db.Time)
    end_time = db.Column(db.Time)
    date = db.Column(db.Date,nullable=True)

And everytime I try to run this I get this error:
sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: PostgreSQL ENUM type requires a name.
Does someone know a fix for this? As I said I have tried multiple things but nothing is working
I tried creating the ENUM's on different ways but still nothing is working
